# mysql multi threading for a single query

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I have big db of size 8GB and having 9 million contacts in this db. When we try to retrieve all contacts, it takes nearly 1 or 2 hour (in some cases result in timeout) to retreive all contacts for the excecution for a single query. Also I have 8 CPU and 24GB RAM, Xeon Processor, the mysql process won't distribute accross the 8 CPU's. My question is that, does we can enable multi threading for a single query.

Awaiting for your Reply

Comment: Are the tables that have those 9 million rows in InnoDB or MyISAM format?

Answer (score 10):

Neither MyISAM nor InnoDB have multithreaded query implementation. Nor do other XtraDB, TokuDB.
It is a long standing issue and limitation of MySQL. I don't know that the limitation is within the MySQL server, but rather in the storage engine implementation. No one ever did it...

I'm currently evaluating the column-store InfiniDB and Infobright IEE. They both support multi-cpu queries and the difference is overwhelming (due to multiple reasons, but CPU being obvious one).

You might want to look at [Shard Query](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/shard-query/), a proxy to MySQL which splits your query into multiple queries, executes them on parallel processes and returns the aggregated result.

Comment: It's horrible this has not been fixed by now.  
Innodb: I have 10-13mb/sec read rates single query. When splitting the read up into 20 queries I can reach up to 400mb/sec read.  
From an IO point of few it's ridiculous but it's just how the engine behaves.

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to discern what order the query should perform its task, but I think it would be good if MySQL had an option, acknowledging query-order will be unpredictable. Also, the link to Shard Query appears to be: https://github.com/greenlion/swanhart-tools/tree/master/shard-query as the link posted leads to something irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

I read a good blog post on some approaches to this recently;

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/01/07/increasing-slow-query-performance-with-parallel-query-execution/

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not offer a way to split the processing of a single query across multiple threads.  Instead, I recommend to implement parallelism in the application layer.  MySQL will happily process separate SELECT statements in parallel.  If you have an auto-increment ID, you can subdivide the table into *N* parts by using `SELECT ... WHERE id % N = 0`.  Use *N* processes or threads to handle each select statement.  Multiple processes is a bit easier to set up than than multiple threads.  You can use xargs to run multiple processes in parallel.

See [MySQL 8.0 FAQ: Does MySQL 8.0 work with multi-core processors?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-general.html#faq-mysql-support-multi-core) :

> A single core is usually used to service the commands issued from one session.

Comment: Is this still valid for MySQL 8 in 2021?